# Return statement of a function doesn't get triggered after using it in Express FileUpload .mv() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file through `Express File Upload` but getting an undefined value of the function in which it is being called.

I have this function which checks if the user chose a single file or multiple files. To keep it simple I am just going to show the issue in single file upload. That is `req.files.fileInput` is an object instead of an array of objects.

Here's the code:

```
const fileCheck = ( file ) => {

     if ( Array.isArray( file ) ) {

        // ignore this part of the if block as I'm testing it out with single file upload

        console.log( 'THE USER WANTS TO UPLOAD MULTIPLE FILES' );

     } else if ( typeof file === 'object' ) {

        console.log( 'THE USER WANTS TO UPLOAD A SINGLE FILE' );

        const uploadPath = `./resources/images/${file.name}`;

        file.mv( uploadPath, function ( err ) {
            if ( err ) {
                console.error( err );

                return {
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Something went wrong. Please upload again!',
                    data: null
                };
            }

            return {
                success: true,
                message: 'File Uploaded Successfully!',
                data: file.name
            }; 

        });

     }

};


const { success, message, data } = fileCheck(req.files.fileInput);

// IT IS UNDEFINED BUT IT IS SUPPOSED TO BE TRUE IF FILE UPLOAD IS SUCCESSFUL.
// IT IS ALSO UNDEFINED INSTEAD OF FALSE IF THERE IS AN ERROR IN FILE UPLOAD. 
console.log( success );
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'success' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
```

Seems like `fileCheck` function's return statement isn't getting triggered after using it in .mv() method. What could be the reason here? And what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only returning from the `file.mv()` callback function, you need to return `file.mv()` as well, such that it percolates up to your `fileCheck` function.

Do this

```js
return file.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);

    return {
      success: false,
      message: 'Something went wrong. Please upload again!',
      data: null,
    };
  }

  return {
    success: true,
    message: 'File Uploaded Successfully!',
    data: file.name,
  };
});
```

#### EDIT

Unfortunately the `file.mv()` doesn't seem to return the result of its callback function by default.

Consider returning a promise from `fileCheck` like this

```js
const fileCheck = ( file ) => {
  if ( Array.isArray( file ) ) {
     console.log( 'THE USER WANTS TO UPLOAD MULTIPLE FILES' );
  } else if ( typeof file === 'object' ) {

     console.log( 'THE USER WANTS TO UPLOAD A SINGLE FILE' );
     const uploadPath = `./resources/images/${file.name}`;

     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
       file.mv( uploadPath, function ( err ) {
         if ( err ) {
             console.error( err );

             return reject({
                 success: false,
                 message: 'Something went wrong. Please upload again!',
                 data: null
             });
         }

         return resolve({
             success: true,
             message: 'File Uploaded Successfully!',
             data: file.name
         }); 

     });
  }
};
```

And using `fileCheck` like this

```js
const { success, message, data } = await fileCheck(req.files.fileInput);
console.log( success );
```

**NB:** You have to make the parent function where `fileCheck` is being called `async` in other to use `await`

Comment: hey man. Thanks for your time. I just tried what you mentioned and put 'return' infront of file.mv(). Sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure you're getting a different error now, tell me what that error is? @s.khan

Comment: Surprisingly it's the same as shown in the OP. That is success is undefined.

Comment: @s.khan it looks like `file.mv` doesn't return anything from the callback result. So I used a promise see my updated answer.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly for the ```resolve``` part when there is no error. But if there is an error, the ```reject``` part just throws the whole reject object in the console instead of just success to false. I'm not logging the whole object in the console. I'm only trying to show the value of success in the above code. Though I need all of those values but why would it log the whole reject object when i'm logging only success?

Comment: Then use resolve when there's an error too and it should work fine, cos reject will always throw and you can only get the result of an error when you chain a `.catch()` at the end of the `fileCheck` function. @s.khan

Comment: Thanks so much mate. It's working as I needed.

Comment: Hey man, how are you doing? Sorry to bother you again. But I had another question regarding this. Your solution works perfectly when I want to upload a single file. That is, the ```else if``` block in the above function. What if I have multiple files which are objects in an array (```if``` block in the above function).  The ```return new Promise``` doesn't seem to work in that case. If I use  ```return new Promise```  for multilple files then the first file gets uploaded only. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hey man, can you post another question for this and send me the link to it here so I can answer it for you. @s.khan

Comment: hey man. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639396/multiple-file-upload-only-uploads-the-first-one-after-using-express-file-upload

Comment: Ok, let me check it out @s.khan

Comment: I just posted a solution for you, let me know if it works @s.khan