# Multiple file upload only uploads the first one after using Express File Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm working on a function which takes in an array of file data that is acquired from user input from the front end. The files are inside `req.files.fileInput` which is an array of objects of file data.

In that function I'm looping through that array of objects of file data to upload one by one. Basically the idea is, start uploading and if it fails to upload then the stop the whole thing by returning an object with `success: false`. And if all the files are uploaded succesfully then return a final object with ````success: true```.

Right now the first file gets uploaded and a return object with `success: true` is shown. And the loop doesn't even go to the second file.

Here's how `req.files` look:

```
{
  fileInput: [
    {
      name: '1.jpg',
      data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 44 6f 02 10 00 00 ... 123608 more bytes>,
      size: 123658,
      encoding: '7bit',
      tempFilePath: '',
      truncated: false,
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      md5: '3b8e39e3ed9a26edda2f3713fcb95f4a',
      mv: [Function: mv]
    },
    {
      name: '2.jpg',
      data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 02 00 00 00 ... 165835 more bytes>,
      size: 165885,
      encoding: '7bit',
      tempFilePath: '',
      truncated: false,
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      md5: '35021d52e7d634042e604fcabf35ccf4',
      mv: [Function: mv]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the function that takes in `req.files.fileInput` array:

```
const uploadFunc = ( fileDataArr ) => {

    for ( let eachFile of fileDataArr ) {

         const fileName   = eachFile.name;
         const uploadPath = `./images/${fileName}`; 

         return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

             eachFile.mv( uploadPath, function ( err ) {
                        
                 if ( err ) {
                      return resolve( {
                          success: false,
                          message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again!',
                          data: null
                      });
                  }

             });

             return resolve( {
                  success: true,
                  message: 'Files Uploaded Successfully',
                  data: null
             });

         });
    }

};

uploadFunc(req.files.fileInput);
```

Comment: You're trying to have your `uploadFunc()` function return as many times as there are files in `fileDataArr`, but a function can return only once - in this case, it does so on the first iteration of the loop, which means the loop actually ends there.

Comment: @IAmDranged What can be done in this situation?

Comment: You probably could wrap the whole loop in the Promise executor function, and resolve only when all files have actually completed upload - keeping track of the iteration count with a local state variable if need be. Note you need to resolve the promise asynchronously from within the `mv()` callback function in order to actually wait until the files have actually completed upload.

Comment: The cleaner and more readable way would be to convert your code to use the `async/await` syntax. This would require to promisify the `mv()` asynchronous function first - ie turn it into a promise-based function. Look this up if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: if you could, then provide an answer as I'm not used to JS Promises :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IAmDranged solution is great. However, you can also do this

- Move `file.mv()` process into its own promise function called `fileMoveAsync(file)`
- Map through all the files and pass each to the `fileMoveAsync(file)`
- Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await all the `fileMoveAsync(file)`
- If all goes well with the `Promise.all()` then `resolve` otherwise `reject` promise accordingly

See code below.

The `fileMoveAsync` function

```js
const fileMoveAsync = async (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadPath = `./resources/images/${file.name}`;
    return file.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);

        return reject({
          success: false,
          message: 'Something went wrong. Please upload again!',
          data: null,
        });
      }

      return resolve({
        success: true,
        message: 'File Uploaded Successfully!',
        data: file.name,
      });
    });
  });
```

```js
const uploadFunc = async (file) => {
  if (Array.isArray(file)) {
    try {
      const data = await Promise.all(file.map((x) => fileMoveAsync(x)));
      return Promise.resolve({
        success: true,
        message: 'Files Uploaded Successfully!',
        data,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject({
        success: false,
        message: 'Something went wrong. Please upload again!',
        data: null,
      });
    }
  } else if (typeof file === 'object') {
    return fileMoveAsync(file);
  }
};
```

Use it like this

```js
const { success, message, data } = await uploadFunc(req.files.fileInput);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a quick and dirty solution that should nonetheless work:

- wrap the whole loop in the `Promise` executor function.
- introduce a local `count` state to keep track of the number of loop iteration that have completed successfully.
- introduce a `isInError` state to keep track of whether a loop iteration has failed.
- In all cases, resolve - or reject - the promise only on the first iteration that results in an error, or when all files have completed upload successfully.

---

```
const uploadFunc = (fileDataArr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var count = fileDataArr.length
        var isInError = false

        for (let eachFile of fileDataArr) {
            const fileName = eachFile.name;
            const uploadPath = `./images/${fileName}`;

            eachFile.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
                if (err && !isInError) {
                    isInError = true
                    return resolve({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again!',
                        data: null
                    });
                }

                if (--count == 0 && !isInError) {
                    return resolve({
                        success: true,
                        message: 'Files Uploaded Successfully',
                        data: null
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Note I have stuck with your logic of resolving the promise when an error occurs - but rejecting may actually make more sense and is actually more semantically correct.

As I pointed out in the comments, look up promisifying asynchronous functions and the `async/await` syntax for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hey man, your answer is great but I'm choosing the other one for other people as it looks cleaner and simpler to understand.

Comment: Sure, no problem.